# dividing a text file to train and test datastes in python3

Tags: python

I have a data file like this example:

example:

```
     X  Y month  day  FFMC    DMC     DC   ISI  RH  wind  rain   area
68   2  2   sep  fri  92.4  117.9  668.0  12.2  33   6.3   0.0   0.00
228  4  6   sep  sun  93.5  149.3  728.6   8.1  26   3.1   0.0  64.10
387  5  5   mar  thu  90.9   18.9   30.6   8.0  48   5.4   0.0   0.00
```

I am trying to split it to train and test sets randomly but based on the columns not rows, also from the 3rd column to the end and the first 2 columns will be included in both train and test sets.

here is the expected output:

train set:

```
     X  Y   month   day FFMC    DC  ISI RH  area
68   2  2   sep fri 92.4    668.0   12.2    33  0.00
228  4  6   sep sun 93.5    728.6   8.1 26  64.10
387  5  5   mar thu 90.9    30.6    8.0 48  0.00
```

test set:

```
     X  Y   DMC wind    rain
68   2  2   117.9   6.3 0.0
228  4  6   149.3   3.1 0.0
387  5  5   18.9    5.4 0.0
```

to do so, I made the following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt', sep="\t")
columns = data.columns
keep = ['X','Y']
columns.drop(keep)
fraction = 0.2
cut = max(1, int((1-fraction)*len(columns)))
train = columns[:cut] #returns the list of headers for train
test = columns[cut:] #returns the list of headers for test
```

but I have 2 problems:
1- since train and test are list of headers, how to add the remaining rows to train and test?
2- how can I add X and Y to both train and test?

do you know how I can do that?

Comment: It's confusing, why are you using different columns in train and test set?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to assign columns after droping

```
columns = columns.drop(keep)
```

And now you can use list with names of columns in `data[ ... ]` and add `keep` to both lists.

```
train_data = data[ keep + train.to_list() ]
test_data  = data[ keep + test.to_list() ]
```

---

Working example:

```
import pandas as pd

text = '''X  Y month  day  FFMC    DMC     DC   ISI  RH  wind  rain   area
2  2   sep  fri  92.4  117.9  668.0  12.2  33   6.3   0.0   0.00
4  6   sep  sun  93.5  149.3  728.6   8.1  26   3.1   0.0  64.10
5  5   mar  thu  90.9   18.9   30.6   8.0  48   5.4   0.0   0.00'''

import io

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

keep = ['X','Y']

columns = data.columns.drop(keep)
fraction = 0.2
cut = max(1, int((1-fraction)*len(columns)))

train = columns[:cut] # unique headers for train
test = columns[cut:]  # unique headers for test

print(data[ keep + train.to_list() ])
print(data[ keep + test.to_list() ])
```